# Counting files from either Photo or Drive App

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

The goal is to download all photos stored on Google: then verify that all photos are downloaded with a file count.

Photos were synced / backedup with Google-Photos.  The procedure to use [Google-Drive to download all photos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/7652919?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) is to be used.  Some photos are deleted \ culled via Ubuntu Firefox web-browser before the download.

```
PROCEDURE:  On your computer, go to drive.google.com    
Click Settings Settings and then Create a Google Photos folder.
In My Drive, find and open the Google Photos folder.
Select the folder you want to download.
Click More More and then Select All and then Download
```

The Ubuntu file browser can quickly count the number of files downloaded.  This number is to be compared with a file count on the Google application side.

## QUESTION

How can the **number of files** in the Google Drive **Photos** **FOLDER** (which should be the same number in Google photo?) be systematically counted?  There are too many photos to count manually.

Comment: If you have images from your Drive synced with Google Photos, those images will not be located in the Google Photos folder, hence, the image count in Google Photos may be higher.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you are using Ubuntu, I can recommend two ways to mount your Google Drive onto your desktop. With either of these methods, the files will not be downloaded, but the drive will be 'virtual' and you will easily be able to use the file browser to count the files.

1. Ubuntu uses the GNOME desktop environment, so you can go to the settings, online accounts, and add your Google Drive account. Your Google Drive will be mounted in the file browser.
2. You can use [`google-drive-ocamlfuse`](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) to mount your Google Drive and view it in your file browser. This method works with other Linux distributions as well.

You can use these tools to access your Google Drive normally, as whenever you click to open a file, it will be downloaded.

Comment: Clever.  An innovative solution.